# Python datetime class: datetime module

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am bit confuse, how this code works?:

```
import datetime as dt

d = dt.datetime.now() # 2022-09-17 16:52:15.615285
```

we know that `datetime` is a class of the `dt` module, but why we can access to a method even knowing we did't create an object of the class before, how this works? and how is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an instance because [`now`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) is a classmethod.